# How to make shadows shorter in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sklightnode

I don't want shadows to be that long (sorry, can't post pictures yet). Is there any property for SKLightNode, like distance, to make shadows shorter? And if not, how do you usually implement dynamic shadows in SpriteKit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SKLightNode class is unfortunately somewhat sparse in its present form. At present it's limited to which nodes can cast shadows, which nodes are covered from cast shadows and light sources.

There is no way to set a a node's shadow length.